# how to pass value to form action laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have a table to view data containing name and id 
i want when clicking edit button to show this data in form in the same page to edit it
and this was made in JS

edit button which i pass the details

```
<button onclick="openForm2('{{ $t->name }}');"> edit </button>
```

the JS function

```
    function openForm2($val) {
        document.getElementById("name").value = $val;
    }
```

the form to update

```
    <form method="post"   action="{{route('type.update',$t->id)}}"
                class="form-container">
        <h1>edit type</h1>
        @csrf
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

        <input type="text"
               name="name"
               id="name"
               required>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">edit</button>
    </form>
```

the problem is the action of the form

```
action="{{route('type.update',$t->id)}}
```

how to pass the id of the clicked element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your route 'type.update' endpoint is '/type/{id}' then Laravel Blade will render

{{route('type.update', $t->id)}} as 'http://your-url.com/type/5'.

If you want JavaScript to set an id, you need to update the action and set the action to 'http://your-url.com/type/5'.

```
//Blade
<button onclick="openForm2('{{ $t->name }}', '{{route('type.update', $t->id)}}');"> edit </button> //Pass the route as action to JS function

<form method="post" action="{{route('type.update',$t->id)}}" class="form-container" id="my-form"> //Set id to "my-form" used by JS

//JS
function openForm2(type, action) {

  document.getElementById("name").value = val;

  var form = document.getElementById("my-form");

  form.action = action; // Update your form with the action containing your new id used for submit

}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)